# Create list of paths taken

Tags: haskell

Given range `(a,b)` and lines `(x,y)`, I want to construct all the possible ways to cover the range with the given lines.

For example with range `(0,10)` (if we filter list to be within range then we don't have to worry about it) and the following list (sorting it makes easier to pick next value),

```
list = [(0,1), (1,10), (1,4), (3,5), (5,10)]
```

I want to output list of paths taken to cover the range as follows,

```
[
[(0,1), (1,4), (3,5), (5,10)],
[(0,1), (1,10)]
]
```

I tried setting up function that would get list of next possible `(x,y)` values as follows, but it only prints a single path.

```
-- assume list is sorted based on first pair
nextpaths :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a, a)] -> ([(a, a)], [(a, a)])
nextpaths ((start, end):xs) = go xs ([], [])
  where go [] acc = acc
        go (y:ys) (next, rest)| fst y <= end = go ys (y:next, rest)
                              | otherwise = (next, y:ys)

paths t@(x:xs) = case nextpaths t of
  ([],_) -> [[x]]
  (n:next, rest) -> map (x:) (paths (n:rest))
```

How would we make it so that `paths` functions applies to other `next` list values?

Comment: Why is `[(0,1), (1,4), (1,10)]` not a valid path?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I suppose it is not _minimal_ in that some intervals _(namely, 1 — 4)_ may be removed safely. I think we should take it as implied that they are minimal paths that are of interest in this problem.

Comment: Yes, the end result is to look for path with minimum number of lines.

Comment: @phoxd: *minimum*, or *minimal*?

Comment: Would minimum mean that there is possibility of multiple minimum paths? And minimal that there is only one minimal option?

Comment: @phoxd The other way around, although it may be better to say _"the_ least _element"_ to avoid any possibility of misreading. You may consult a book on order theory, like this [Introduction to Lattices and Order](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/introduction-to-lattices-and-order/946458CB6638AF86D85BA00F5787F4F4), if you wish to know the precise formulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can generate a list of *minimal* paths: paths where we can not remove a single 2-tuple such that it is still a valid path.

Usually it is more efficient here to work with a sorted list of fragments, since we can scan the list and append items that are necessary. When we scan, we will need two things: the range we want to cover; and the last range, such that we guarantee minimality.

We will first construct a function where we assume we already selected a path. We thus can define a function with signature:

```
paths1 :: Ord a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> [(a, a)] -> [[(a, a)]]
```

In case the last item selected is greater than or equal to the upperbound of the range, we are done. In that case, we return a singleton list with an empty list. The recursive call can then add the selected subpath to the list:

```
paths1 (a, f) (b, c) _ | c >= f = [[]]
```

In case the list of possible subranges is exhausted, we can not generate such path, we thus return an empty list in case the list of subranges is empty:

```
paths1 _ _ [] = []
```

In case we have not reached the end yet, we will need an extra subrange. Such subrange needs to satisfy two criteria: it should start *after* the previously selected subpath, and it should end *after* the previously selected subpath. We thus can skip suranges that do not satisfy that condition:

```
paths1 r s@(b, c) ((d, e):xs) | d > c = []
                              | d <= b || e <= c = paths1 r s xs
```

In case we can select the subrange, we thus can pick that one. In that case we thus update the last range selected and will the prepend all the paths that are returned:

```
paths1 r s@(_,sb) (x@(_, xb):xs) = map (x:) (paths1 r (sb,xb) xs) ++ paths1 r s xs
```

Now we thus have defined a complete implementation for `paths1`:

```
paths1 :: Ord a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> [(a, a)] -> [[(a, a)]]
paths1 (a, f) (b, c) _ | c >= f = [[]]
paths1 _ _ [] = []
paths1 r s@(b, c) ((d, e):xs) | d > c = []
                              | d <= b || e <= c = paths1 r s xs
paths1 r s@(_,sb) (x@(_, xb):xs) = map (x:) (paths1 r (sb,xb) xs) ++ paths1 r s xs
```

We now need to implement a function that selects the first subrange. We can implement such function `path0`:

```
paths0 :: (a, a) -> [(a, a)] -> [[(a, a)]]
```

The first range we should select should start before on on the start of the range we want to generate, and after the start of the range. We thus can implement that as:

```
paths0 :: Ord a => (a, a) -> [(a, a)] -> [[(a, a)]]
paths0 (a, _) ((b, c):_) | b > a || c <= a = []
paths0 r@(a, _) ((_, c):xs) | c <= a = paths0 r xs
paths0 r (x:xs) = map (x:) (paths1 r x xs) ++ paths0 r xs
```

So now we can combine the two in a `path` function. We can first sort the list, or add this as a pre-condition:

```
import Data.List(sort)

paths :: (a, a) -> [(a, a)] -> [[(a, a)]]
paths = (. sort) . paths0
```

We then obtain the expected result:

```
Prelude Data.List> paths (0,10) [(0,1), (1,10), (1,4), (3,5), (5,10)]
[[(0,1),(1,4),(3,5),(5,10)],[(0,1),(1,10)]]
```

The above is not the most elegant solution. I leave "*polishing*" it further as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I am confused as to how pattern matching with guards that do not have `otherwise` case.  In your usage of `paths1 (a, f) (b, c) _ | c >= f = [[]]`, Does compiler decide to go to the next pattern below if it doesn't match?

Comment: @phoxd: yes indeed. If the guard fails, it continues with the next patterns.

Comment: Your algorithm is at fault. Consider `paths (2, 5) [(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 6)]`: it will offer, among others, `[(1,3),(2,4),(3,6)]`, which is not minimal: `(2, 4)` is extraneous. Indeed, the smaller `[(1,3),(3,6)]` is also offered.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov: thanks for the feedback. That was indeed a case I forgot, although I think with some changes it can be fixed :)

Comment: @IgnatInsarov: I hope that is now fixed :)

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can see, `(0, 2) [(-2, 1), (-1, 2)]` still gives `[(-2,1),(-1,2)],[(-1,2)]]`, which again includes a chain that is not minimal.

Answer (score 3):

#### This is actually a problem of some depth.

Or, rather, the algorithm you ask for is simple *(if approached with the right tools at hand)*;
but checking whether it is correct is not, and it is very easy to make a slight mistake. This is
because intervals are unlike numbers in that there is no such simple notion as the usual total
order anymore, and what relations we have instead are tenfold more complex — too far so for the
unarmed human mind to grasp.

Therefore, what our goals should be?

1. We need to understand how intervals relate to each other.
2. We need to be able to check if a given set of intervals is a solution to the problem.

In this writing, I will be saying *"base"* meaning the interval to be covered, and *"chain"*
consisting of *"links"* meaning a set of intervals that may be covering it. *(I will eventually
justify this latter naming.)*

#### So, let us arm ourselves.

With numbers *(that is, single points)*, there are only 3 disjoint qualitative relations: `a < b`
or `a = b` or `a > b`. What can we say about pairs of numbers *(representing intervals)* then?
There are 5 places a point can be with respect to an interval:

```
             on the left end
             v
-- before -- * == inside == * -- after --
                            ^
                            on the right end
```

Considering that the left end of an interval is never to the right of its right end *(duh)*, this
gives us `sum [5, 4.. 1] = 15` disjoint qualitative relations between two intervals. Disregarding
the two relations where both ends of one interval are on the same end of another *(meaning the
interval is a point)*, that gives 13. And now there is a [prior art](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~alspaugh/cls/shr/allen.html) discussing exactly 13
disjoint exhaustive relations on intervals. *([Original article.](https://cse.unl.edu/~choueiry/Documents/Allen-CACM1983.pdf))*

Namely, there are defined these 6 relations:

```
precedes      =  \ i j  ->  right i < left j
meets         =  \ i j  ->  right i == left j && left i /= left j && right i /= right j
overlaps      =  \ i j  ->  left i < left j  && right i < right j && right i > left j
isFinishedBy  =  \ i j  ->  left i < left j  && right i == right j
contains      =  \ i j  ->  left i < left j  && right i > right j
starts        =  \ i j  ->  left i == left j && right i < right j
```

— Together with their inversions `flip ...` and the equality relation.

Whereas for numbers we can derive exactly 8 composite relations in terms of the 3 basic ones
*(considering relations as a vector space over the binary field)*, on intervals we can define
about 8 *thousand*. Some of those will be of use to us within this problem:

```
absorbs         =  isFinishedBy `or` contains `or` flip starts `or` (==)
isDisjointWith  =  precedes     `or` flip precedes
joins           =  (fmap . fmap) not isDisjointWith
touches         =  meets        `or` overlaps
isRightwardsOf  =  flip (precedes `or` touches)
...
```

Given these relations, we can manipulate them to obtain all kinds of awesome devices, such as
closures, equivalences and orders. I will presently use some to obtain a verifier of solutions to
our problem.

1. A reflexive, symmetric and transitive closure of `joins` is an equivalence under which
   considered equivalent are those intervals that belong to a contiguous line. *(While not
   necessarily being adjacent on that line.)*
2. A *normal* set of intervals is such in which all intervals are disjoint.

   - Any set may be *normalized* by gluing together intervals that join until none are left.
   - Normalization preserves coverage: exactly when a point belongs to some of the intervals in a
     set, it will belong to some interval in its normalization.
3. A solution is a chain such that:

   - Its normalization is a singleton set whose only member `absorbs` the base. *(Sufficient.)*
   - With any link removed, this condition does not anymore hold. *(Minimal.)*

Therefore, `normalize` is a function that divides a set of intervals into classes of equivalence
induced by `joins` and converts each class to an interval by taking the extrema of all the
endpoints.

```
relation :: Ord a => Set a -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> Relation a

closure :: Relation a -> Relation a

classifyBy :: Ord a => (a -> a -> Bool) -> Set a -> Set (Set a)

(?) :: Eq a => Relation a -> (a, a) -> Bool

bounds :: Ord a => Set a -> Interval a

flatten :: Ord a => Set (Interval a) -> Set a

normalize :: Ord a => Set (Interval a) -> Set (Interval a)
normalize u | Set.null u = Set.empty
            | otherwise = let  rel = closure (relation u joins)
                               classes = classifyBy (curry (rel ?)) u
                          in Set.map (bounds . flatten) classes
```

In these terms, we can define the check:

```
isCovering :: Ord a => Interval a -> [Interval a] -> Bool
isCovering base xs = case (Set.toList . normalize . Set.fromList) xs of
                        [y] -> y `absorbs` base
                        _   -> False

isMinimalCovering :: Ord a => Interval a -> [Interval a] -> Bool
isMinimalCovering base xs = sufficient && minimal
    where sufficient = isCovering base xs
          minimal    = List.null . filter (isCovering base)
                                 . fmap (`deleteAt` xs) $ [0.. length xs - 1]
```

Not only that, we can define a filter:

```
bruteForceCoveringChains :: forall a. (Ord a, Num a)
                         => Interval a -> [Interval a] -> [[Interval a]]
bruteForceCoveringChains base xs = filter (isMinimalCovering base) (List.subsequences xs)
```

Time complexity of these devices is crazy. Empirically, this brute force solution can munch
through a set of 10 intervals, but not 20. But this much is enough to check a candidate fast
algorithm against.

#### Onwards now!

All the links in our chain must connect, like... links of a chain. One after the other. There is a
relation for that: the one I named `touches`. If a series of intervals consecutively touch one
another, we are certain that they cover the space from the beginning of the first to the ending of
the last one. We can use this relation to consecutively filter more and more links into our chain
until it subsumes the base completely.

Incidentally, `touches` is an antisymmetric relation, which makes its transitive and reflexive
closure an *ordering* of intervals, and a *chain* in order theory is exactly a totally ordered
set. So, our naming is justified: there is a relation that is not a total ordering for arbitrary
sets of intervals, but is a total ordering for our chains.

This is not enough though: we must also ensure our chain is minimal. I claim that this condition
holds exactly when `touches` is *nowhere transitive* on our chain. That means: when
`` x `touches` y `` and `` y `touches` z ``, it is never that `` x `touches` z `` *(Otherwise, we would
not need `y` in our chain.)*.  Observe that, like links in a real chain, our *"links"* must only
overlap two at a time. This requirement may be paraphrased in terms of interval relations: a link
must *be touched by* the interval between the end of the previous link and the one before the
previous. It sounds a bit baroque, but I am sure the reader may depict this situation in their
mind or on a piece of paper.

And this is all that is needed to give a recursive definition that we are looking for.

```
chainsFromTo :: Ord a => Interval a -> Interval a -> [Interval a] -> [[Interval a]]
chainsFromTo start end xs' = case base of
    Point _ -> (fmap pure . filter (`absorbs` base)) xs'
    _       -> baseCase ++ recursiveCase
  where
    base = right start ~~ left end

    xs = filter (not . isDisjointWith base) xs'

    baseCase = do
        x <- filter ((start `touches`) * (`touches` end)) xs
        return [x]

    recursiveCase = do
        x <- filter ((start `touches`) * not . (`touches` end)) xs
        xs <- chainsFromTo (right start ~~ right x) end (filter (`isRightwardsOf` x) xs)
        return $ x: xs

coveringChainsFromTo :: forall a. (Ord a, Num a)
                     => Interval a -> [Interval a] -> [[Interval a]]
coveringChainsFromTo _   [ ] = [ ]
coveringChainsFromTo base xs = chainsFromTo start end xs
  where
    start = (\z -> z - 1) (left reach) ~~ left base
    end = right base ~~ (\z -> z + 1) (right reach)
    reach = (bounds . flatten . Set.fromList) xs
```

Once you have it, it looks straightforward, but I tried like a dozen times to make it right, and
only extensive checking helped me locate and fix all the corner cases. You can see the complete
code in [a repository](https://github.com/kindaro/interval-cover).

#### That is it.

I hope it helps. Do comment if my presentation is not clear or if I missed something.